# How to Split a byte into 2 parts and read it?

Tags: c#, winforms, integer

I encountered this problem on a task given to me.
Here's the situation:

[image]

> If the user clicks on "Vat First" then the value is 0.
> Else, the value is 1.

Then, in this Textbox,

[image]

> The range of the value permitted is 0 to 15.

Then the example values are saved like this:

"01" = since it's vat first and 1mm Z-axis Up height.

"11" = Platform First, 1mm Z-axis up

"015" = vat first, 15mm

"115" = platform first, 15mm

> The reason why it is saved like this because it is the file protocol given to me, and I can't do anything about it. It says there that the value is "Platform Moving order and Z Axis Up height" in 1 byte value.

My problem now is reading the result afterwards for reloading it to the application. How do I know if it just uses 3 or 2 digits since the return of int disregards the 0 in the beginning. "015" = "15" so my application might treat it as Platform First, 5 mm rather than Vat first, 15mm.

> Edit: So I just realized thanks to @BenVoigt, that it is saved into a byte and it has 8 bits. According to the protocol given to me, the first 4-bits is the moving order (0 or 1) and the rest is for the Z-Axis Up Height (0-15). For the real question, how do I separate the byte into 4 bits each and get the value?

Comment: Why????? Can't you just do JSON or at least comma separated list like 0,15?

Comment: Ow. I forgot to tell you that it is a file protocol given to me. I can't do anything about it @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: But it is *text* file protocol? How do you get "015" and "15" strings to be the same then?

Comment: Please refer to the code. @AlexeiLevenkov. I used ToString("D3") to treat them as 3 digit number, before assessing the values. And that is the problem if I saved the values as 2 digits only.

Comment: With your clarification, the task is impossible.  Think you'd better make the "platform first" worth +100, instead of prepending a `'1'` digit.  It also could work in the other order, with `value = 10 * zShift + (platformFirst? 1: 0)`

Comment: @TerribleDog you mean some #$@# made `PlatformVatMovingOrder` of type `int` when they read non-int values from text stream ? (Side note please re-read [MCVE] guidance - it is very hard to see what exactly happening in your case )

Comment: @BenVoigt This is what I'm thinking to. Impossible unless I find a way to tell me if I saved it for 3 digits or 2 digits.

Comment: @TerribleDog: If it's been stuffed into a byte, then it hasn't been saved with either 2 digits or 3 digits.  It's been saved with 8 bits.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, the first 4 bits is for the Moving Order and the rest is for the Height. Is it possible to get the two apart?

Comment: @TerribleDog: Well that's an entirely different thing, and it is easy.  `Order = Combined >> 4; Height = Combined & 0x0F;`  And saving: `Combined = (Order << 4) | Height;`  The `<<` and `>>` are the bitshift operators.

Comment: @BenVoigt Maybe you can help me for that. I'll change my question.

Comment: This question could have benefited a lot without all the business logic, it was exceedingly difficult to understand

Comment: @MichaelRandall I understand, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the first 4-bits is the moving order (0 or 1) and the rest is for the Z-Axis Up Height (0-15).

This is a straightforward bit-shifting task.

```
Order = Combined >> 4;
Height = Combined & 0x0F;
```

And saving:

```
Combined = (Order << 4) | Height;
```

The `<<` and `>>` are the bitshift operators.

Comment: If you go for just bit-shifting :) - `Height = ((byte)(Combined  << 4)) >>4;` (but this all really answered many times already)...

Answer (score -1):

Can’t you just make both results strings and just append them together for your result? It seems that the integer type is your issue.

Comment: Nah, his issue is not showing the real definition in the file protocol document.  Apparently (from comments) there's 4 bits for each item, non-overlapping, no problem.